# Which space debris are used for science purpose?

Tags: debris, science

I already know that some Apollo's space debris were used for [seismic study](https://www.history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-26_S-IVB_Lunar_Impact.htm) of the Moon.

Other debris may be used for scientific studies. By debris, I mean space objects that have no purpose or already fulfill there missions (e.g. rocket stages, decommissioned satellites) I'm thinking of gravity fluctuation study influencing space object's trajectory, but I have no idea if this has already done.

My question is: except the well-known Apollo's seismic study, what other space debris (from any space program) were used for science?

Comment: If you [use the upper stage of a Centaur rocket as a impactor as part of a planned mission - LCROSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCROSS) is that considered debris?

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes as I considered the S-IVB as one in the question